# crop/select many non-contiguous pixels in a specific dimension of a netcdf

Tags: netcdf

I have a netcdf file which I'd like to split in 4 geographical parts.

This file has these dimensions :

```
time = UNLIMITED; // (385452 currently)
nlayers = 19;
npressures = 20;
nchartime = 16;
```

The time dimension is actually a "space.time" dimension.
Latitudes and longitudes are put as variables.
I open lat and lon variables with matlab and select the pixels contained in the area to keep.
How to say to NCO/CDO : extract only these pixels in the "time" dimension ? (selected pixels are not contiguous)

```
ncks -d time indexPixel1,indexPixel2,...,indexPixel10600 inputFile -O outpuFile
```

does not work since it takes only a range (min,max,stride)

I've also tried

```
cdo sellonlatbox lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 inputFile outpuFile
```

but it says "Unsupported grid type" (lat and lon are as variables and not as dimensions)

```
cdo select,levidx=indexPixel1,indexPixel2,... inputFile outpuFile
```

does not seem appropriate either.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you can do things in Python, there is a somewhat undocumented feature in the last couple of releases nctoolkit package that should be able to solve this (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Just tweak the following:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_data("infile.nc")
ds.assign_coords(lon_name = "lon", lat_name = "lat")
ds.crop(lon = [lon1, lon2], lat = [lat1, lat2])
ds.to_nc("outfile.nc")
```

You will of course need to change the name of "lon" etc. in `assign_coords`. The `assign_coords` method uses NCO to set variables to coords.

Comment: Thank you. The function was not in the version installed with conda or pip so I installed the development version.

    ds = nc.open_data(path + file)
    ds.assign_coords(lon_name = "longitude", lat_name = "latitude")

==> "TypeError: This only works for single files currently"
Which is given by "if type(self.current) is list:"
Although my ds is of type "api.Dataset"
Any idea ?

Comment: My bad. Undocumented/experimental, so I haven't checked it for compatibility with the latest api. I have just updated the development version, so it should work now.

Comment: Lines 71-74 here will show you how the NCO is extracted: https://github.com/pmlmodelling/nctoolkit/blob/master/nctoolkit/esoteric.py

Comment: I still have an error at line 83 : 
nco_command += self.current + " " + target.
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list.
If I replace by :
nco_command += self.current[0] + " " + target.
Then I have an error at line 85 of esoteric.py triggered by line 75 of runthis.py : Attempting to overwrite an opened file.

Comment: My bad again. Looks like I didn't push all my changes. Can you possibly add a link to your file? I can then test `assign_coords` using it

Comment: This one should be fine : https://cds-espri.ipsl.upmc.fr/iasial2/iasi_co/V6.4.0/2019/09/IASI_METOPA_L2_CO_20190921_ULB-LATMOS_V6.4.0.nc

Comment: thanks. I'll have a look. I'll try to create a github gist. I suspect the grid info also needs changed from generic

Comment: OK. I'm looking at the data. The longitude/latitude are pure data points, not true grid info. So there is no way for NCO to convert them to coordinates. I suspect the only pure netcdf way to solve the problem would be to create a mask based on the lon/lat variables and then apply that to the data. Otherwise try xarray/dataframes

Comment: Nice to have your expertise. Do you have a CDO/NCO function in mind to apply the mask ?

Comment: something like this should work: https://gist.github.com/r4ecology/058e8e3ec985150641b9ecf9ee9341a1. That will create a new netcdf file with 1s within a specified lon/lat box and nas elsewhere

Comment: You could potentially do a furrther step of removing the timesteps that have have no data within the lon/lat box

Comment: OK. Just updated the gist so it can subset the time steps. I might see if I can add variable based filtering to nctoolkit

Comment: It seems nice but I have an error at last line : list too long: '/bin/sh'. It does not occur if I take time_steps[0:100]. Also, I would like too keep all variables with drop = False at line 3, but then my computer memory is slowly overflowed and freeze.

Comment: Ah. It sounds like the CDO call nctoolkit is generating is literally too long to terminate. Not something I've run into the in the past, but solutions seem to exist https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. I am trying another solution now, which is to open directly the right pixels (without previous crop).